# Is there a thing that wraps a polling api and exposes websockets?

Tags: node.js, express, websocket, long-polling

We have a web application where the client frequently (every second) polls for changed data. Now we want to write a mobile client, and we're worried about the overhead of all this polling. It's too complicated/costly to modify the APIs, but I figure we should be able to put a thing in the middle, on the server, that maintains websockets with mobile clients, polls the legacy APIs, and pushes out new data over the websocket as it becomes available.

The requirement seems both fairly generic and fairly simple (famous last words). Does such a thing exist already? (I've looked but not found.) If not, should I just get straight in with express/node and write it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think any such thing exists.  As you surmise, it's not complicated to build yourself, but what to poll and how to do that and then what to send from that polling request over the webSocket is entirely specific to your situation.

As you can probably already figure out, you would need something like the following:

1. A webSocket server (perhaps riding on the same port as your existing web server).
2. An interval timer or repeated `setTimeout()` to run the regular polling
3. The http request from the legacy APIs
4. The logic to decide when there is something relevant to send to the clients
5. Logic to decide which webSocket connections to send the data to (all data to the all clients or each client has their own data?).